# $f(z) = \overline{z} e^{-z \overline{z}}$. Does $\frac{d}{dz}f(z)$ exist?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I've just started a complex variable calculus course, I already know about sufficient conditions for a derivative to exist (Cauchy Riemann + Differentiability of u and v).
I'm having some serious doubts about this one, and I don't know whether its derivative exists or not.

Pros for existence:

·Cauchy-Riemann verifies for $z$ where $|z|=1$

·$u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are differentiable. 
So I would say $f(z)$ admits a derivative at points on the unit circumference.

Cons for existence:

·There's $z^*$ and $|z|^2$ implicated here, and I know these are not derivable anywhere (except for $|z|^2$ at the origin).

·Wolfram says it's nowhere differentiable in the complex plane (I don't know how good can a "calculator" for this be and I barely know things about apps like Wolfram, maybe my input there was somehow wrong)
So I'm surprised this composition $f(z)$ is derivable on the unit circumference

Comment: I haven't got to analytic functions yet. As far as I know I think this specific function is not analytic anywhere (because as you said, |z|²=1 is not an open set).
What I'm trying to figure out here is just about the derivative
I've tried finding it via definition but I failed

Comment: Draw a tiny capital "R" in the complex plane. Its image under complex conjugation is a backwards "R". The image of that under the positive-valued function $e^{-\overline z z}$ is still, topologically, a backwards "R". So this thing cannot be holomorphic. Holomorphic functions do not reverse the clockwise-versus-counterclockwise orienation; they preserve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, your function *is* complex differentiable at any point on the unit circle.

It is analytic nowhere, which is likely what WolframAlpha is investigating when it says "nowhere differentiable in the complex plane".  This is because, while there are lots of useful properties of analytic functions (which are the same as complex differentiable on an open set) complex differentiability on a set with empty interior (like a circle) has significantly more limited use.

---

Another example with a similar issue is $g(x+iy) = x^2 + y + i(y^2 − x).$  It is complex-differentiable on the line $y=x$ and nowhere analytic, but WolframAlpha says it is nowhere differentiable in the complex plane.

Comment: Our professor did tell us that almost all functions we will be working with during the course are going to be analytic because of how "well" they behave. So Wolfram apparently checks that. Thanks a lot for anwering!

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry I misinterpreted your question earlier in my now-deleted comment.  I was in effect making the same assumption/error about your question that WolframAlpha seems to make.

Answer (score 0):

The Cauchy-Riemann equations can be written succinctly as
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0.$$

For your function,

$$ \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = e^{-|z|^2} (1-|z|^2).$$

So yes, the function is differentiable only on the unit circle.